# "DEB" packages recovery

Tags: package-management, deb

The main point is to make "deb" packages recovery. As I'm using Ubuntu , I install it several times for friends so I decided to make packages recovery, so I tried "APTonCD" to do but I can't find a choice to restore from ISO file in the program just accept CD !

I tried to burn it on CD also nothing happened as assuming no CD in driver !!, I tried to copy the packages manually then when installing any program can't be completed and an error occur

- Additional problem : Now on my laptop every time I try to install any program it ask for packages CD even if I enter the CD it can't install any package ! so no more program for me!

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution for your additional problem:
Try to start **Software Sources** and look if everything (except for *Source Code*) is checked under "Downloadable from the Internet"

What error-message do you get when trying to install something more precisely?

Comment: thank you but I've checked it before :(....it says:"Insert CD/DVD [CD's name] to download packages from it". However,it seems not to accept the CD when it's in !!

Comment: @wisdom What does it say when you (in the Terminal) try to install for example cowsay (first run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install cowsay`)?

Any error message? (If you've already have got cowsay installed, install something else)

Comment: ...Thanks a lot, it seems to accept installing only new packages which not already was installed ! so program I've removed and trying to re-install it'll ask for CD.....Hmmm, I have some suggestions to try then will feed you back ;)